# Find a file on a PC and replace a string erases whole file

Tags: python, python-2.6

I need to look for a particular file on a pc and replace just a portion of all repeats of a string within the file. I am using Python 2.6. The script finds the file but instead of replacing all instances of the string, it just wipes the file blank. Any idea why?

```
import os
from os.path import join
import fileinput
lookfor = "particular.txt"
textToSearch = "Alonglineoftext@thefile"
textToReplace = "Alonglineoftext@withnewtextinthefile"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\\'):
  print "searching", root
  if lookfor in files:
    for line in fileinput.FileInput((join(root, lookfor)),inplace=1):
        line = line.replace(textToSearch, textToReplace)
        print line
    break
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: you're only replacing the content locally. you have to write it back to the file

Comment: @AshokaLella `print line` does this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested your code and it works fine with only one small bug:

the following line:

```
line = line.replace(textToSearch, textToReplace)
```

should be replaced with:

```
line = line.strip().replace(textToSearch, textToReplace)
```

otherwise each line will be appended with an extra `newline` - this could also be the reason that you don't find the replacements (since you're expecting them to be in different (original) line-numbers)